# grupos opcionales en expresiones regulares

Tags: java, regex

Respondiendo otra pregunta en SO, me surgió la interrogante de como lidiar con expresiones regulares cuando contienen grupos opcionales.

Por ejemplo, si quisiera capturar el número de teléfono y número favorito en el siguiente texto:

> hola mi telefono es 12345678 y mi numero favorito es el 13

Usuaría una expresión como:

```
telefono[^\d]*(\d+).*numero favorito[^\d]*(\d+)
```

Si ambos datos fuesen opcionales, haría algo como:

```
(?:telefono[^\d]*(\d+))?.*(?:numero favorito[^\d]*(\d+))?
```

Pero esa expresión no funciona, ya que `.*` hace *match* de todo y los grupos opcionales quedan vacíos.

La única forma que he encontrado para especificar los caracteres entre ambos grupos para que sigan funcionando es con un *negative lookahead* de todas las cadenas que ocupo en los grupos:

```
(?:telefono[^\d]*(\d+))?(?:(?!telefono|numero favorito).)*(?:numero favorito[^\d]*(\d+))?
```

Si bien con eso ya se logra obtener los grupos opcionales, existen *matchs* posibles en los que no se ocupa ningún grupo. Además algo así no escalaría muy bien para muchos grupos.

¿Existe alguna alternativa?

Comment: no lo había pensado en un lenguaje en particular, pero javascript o java me interesan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Multiples grupos, todos opcionales, diferenciando cada uno en el resultado**

Todo lo que mencionaste en la pregunta tiene sentido, y es un buen análisis del problema. Pero se puede encarar de una forma más fácil. En vez de buscar coincidir con los dos números en 1 única coincidencia, conviene pensar en coincidencias independientes:

```
telefono\D*(\d+)|numero favorito\D*(\d+)
```

De esta forma, en cada coincidencia busca a uno o al otro, y te devolvería una coincidencia para el grupo 1 o el grupo 2 de acuerdo a cual corresponda. Llamamos a [Matcher#find()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find--) mientras siga coincidiendo:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

```
final String regex = "telefono\\D*(\\d+)|numero favorito\\D*(\\d+)";
final String texto = "hola mi telefono es 12345678 y mi numero favorito es el 13";

final Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(texto);

while (matcher.find()) {
    if (matcher.group(1) != null) {
        System.out.println("Tel: " + matcher.group(1));
    } else {
        System.out.println("Num: " + matcher.group(2));
    }
}
```

---

De todas formas, sé que tu pregunta apunta más a la teoría que la práctica. Si los grupos tienen que aparecer *en ese orden* en el texto, siendo igualmente opcionales, entonces, la forma de capturarlos sería agregando al texto intermedio (`.*`) dentro de la parte opcional. Es decir:

```
^(?:.*telefono\D*(\d+))?(?:.*numero favorito\D*(\d+))?
```

Recordemos que el motor de regex es [goloso](http://search.cpan.org/~enell/POD2-ES-5.16.2.02/lib/POD2/ES/perlre.pod#Cuantificadores) (*[greedy](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy)*), por lo que para cada cuantificador, siempre intenta coincidir con lo más posible. En este caso significa que el `(?:`…`)?` intenta con 1 antes que 0... Con eso nos garantizamos recorrer todo el string hasta encontrar una coincidencia (por ejemplo en `.*telefono\D*(\d+)`), y recién tomarlo como opcional si esa parte no coincide.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

```
final String regex = "^(?:.*telefono\\D*(\\d+))?(?:.*numero favorito\\D*(\\d+))?";
final String texto = "hola mi telefono es 12345678 y mi numero favorito es el 13";

final Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(texto);

if (matcher.find()) { // ← if redundante (siempre coincide)
    if (matcher.group(1) != null) {
        System.out.println("Tel: " + matcher.group(1));
    }
    if (matcher.group(2) != null) {
        System.out.println("Num: " + matcher.group(2));
    }
}
```

- Hay que usar [`Pattern.DOTALL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) si se puede extender más allá de un salto de línea.

Si se pueden presentar en cualquier orden, solamente es necesario reemplazar los grupos sin captura `(?:`…`)?` por [inspecciones positivas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#special) (*[lookaheads](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)*) `(?=`…`)?`.

---

Otra forma de tener múltiples grupos opcionales *en orden* es:

```
(?:telefono\D*(\d+).*?)?(?:numero favorito\D*(\d+).*?)?$
```

Lo que hace es que si coincide con uno de los grupos, sigue consumiendo lo menos posible ([no goloso](http://search.cpan.org/~enell/POD2-ES-5.16.2.02/lib/POD2/ES/perlre.pod#Cuantificadores), *[lazy](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy)*) con `.*?` hasta el próximo grupo, pero al mismo tiempo lo estoy obligando a recorrer todo el string hasta coincidir con el final `$`.

Comment: Para darte un ejemplo claro de por qué es importante el lenguaje, en .Net sería una historia completamente diferente `@"^(?:.*?(telefono|numero favorito)\D*(\d+))+"`